# AWS Cognito 에러 Error: connect EHOSTDOWN 169.254.169.254:80 - Local (192.168.1.85:56523)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

While using AWS Cognito, I ran code to revoke a refreshToken and got this error.

`Error: connect EHOSTDOWN 169.254.169.254:80 - Local (192.168.1.85:56523) at internalConnect (node:net:931:16) at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (node:internal/async_hooks:465:18) at node:net:1022:9 at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) { message: 'Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1', errno: -64, code: 'CredentialsError', syscall: 'connect', address: '169.254.169.254', port: 80, time: 2023-04-28T08:33:29.829Z, originalError: { message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers', errno: -64, code: 'CredentialsError', syscall: 'connect', address: '169.254.169.254', port: 80, time: 2023-04-28T08:33:29.829Z, originalError: { message: 'EC2 Metadata roleName request returned error', errno: -64, code: 'EHOSTDOWN', syscall: 'connect', address: '169.254.169.254', port: 80, time: 2023-04-28T08:33:29.829Z, originalError: [Object] } } }`

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is or how to fix it?

I don't know where to start...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.